# Mapping JSON list of SelectListItems to DropDown Select List with Jquery and indicating selected item

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON list of SelectListItems that I grab:

```
             new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = item.Name,
                    Value = item.Id.ToString(),
                    Selected = item.Id.Equals(userId)
                }).ToList();
```

Then this list is connected to a dropdown menu with JQuery:

```
$.Ajax call for an object above goes here...
function (data) {
        data= $.map(data, function (item, a) {
        return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
              });

        $("#edit-user-list").html(data.join(""));
```

This works and populates my list just fine.
I can't figure out syntax how to indicate my SELECTED item though!
Can you guys help me out ?
How with this JQuery can I indicate the selected item that's indicated in the passed in JSON collection of items?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function (data) {
    data= $.map(data, function (item, a) {
    return "<option value=" + item.Value + " " + (item.Selected ? "selected": "") + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
          });

    $("#edit-user-list").html(data.join(""));
```

Comment: Ofcourse...
Nice, thanks for helping out with the brain fart.