# Use Item from ViewModel in jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

In my ViewModel I have a ThemesFilterList:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ThemesFilterList { get; set; }
```

I want to use append this list as `<select>` element to my `<td>` element using javascript/jquery.

So, something like:

```
var td = $(this); //current <td> element.
var ThemesFilterList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ThemesFilterList)); // using my ThemesFilterList from Model.
td.append(ThemesFilterList);
```

Comment: Can you provide `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ThemesFilterList));` result for more help ?

Comment: check if this helps, similar to what you want i guess.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746276/mapping-json-list-of-selectlistitems-to-dropdown-select-list-with-jquery-and-ind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `ThemesFilterList` variable will have a `JSON` object.

```
var ThemesFilterList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ThemesFilterList));
```

From here you can simply loop this JSON object

```
var filterstr = '<select>';

for(var i = 0; i < ThemesFilterList.length; i++) {
    filterstr += '<option>' + ThemesFilterList[i].Value + '</option>';
}

filterstr += '</select>'

td.append(filterstr);
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/651fo4f6/)

Comment: I was hoping to directly add the `var ThemesFilterList` as `<select>` without first iterating through the content.

Comment: Well if render `ThemesFilterList` as a valid DOM element then you can directly append. But still you would need some logic to render it, only this time it would be on a server side.